# Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to integrate the push notification plugin in ionic1.

I followed this tutorial

```
 http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotificationsV5/
```

I installed plugin successfully. 
When i am trying to get token at that time i am gettin an error

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined(…)
```

I think i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just put below code in your app.js

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {     
  var options = {
    android: {
      senderID: "*********"
    },
     ios: {
       alert: "true",
       badge: "true",
       sound: "true"
     },
     windows: {}
   };

   // initialize
   $cordovaPushV5.initialize(options).then(function() {
     $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function(registrationId) {
       console.log("tokenid",registrationId);
     });
   });
});
```